# System.ListException: Invalid id at index 2: null

Tags: apex

Today I was alerted to some exceptions in our production logs.  The logs don't include a stack trace.  The errors are sporadic, and it's not immediately obvious how to reproduce them.  If I could deploy code to production, I could add a stack trace to the logs, but I would have to jump through a bunch of hoops, so I'm hoping to triage this with the info I already have.

This is what I do have from the logs:

- The exception type name: `System.ListException`
- The exception message: **Invalid id at index 2: null**

I've seen plenty of `ListException`s in my day, and a quick Google search will bring up `ListException` messages like:

- [List index out of bounds: 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13670/solve-system-listexception-list-index-out-of-bounds-0): the most common one; happens when you try to refer to an index that doesn't exist
- [Row with null Id at index: 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284260/fatal-errorsystem-listexception-row-with-null-id-at-index-0): can happen in the context of an `AggregateResult` query (note: there are no references to `AggregateResult` in this area of code)
- [Missing id at index: 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140824/visualforce-delete-row-missing-id-at-index-0): happens when you try to delete a record that doesn't exist
- [Row with duplicate Name at index: 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272603/system-listexception-row-with-duplicate-name-at-index-47-error-from-list-cus): can come up when using Custom Settings if a duplicate `Name` value has been introduced

My message looks different than all of these.  What does it mean, and what kind of code antipattern should I be looking for?

Comment: I thought that error would arise from the `Map<Id, SObject>` constructor, but was wrong. That said, it seems possible some aggregate usage might have been missed somewhere, for example if your code calls some other services.

Comment: I feel like I should know what emits this error, but I can't replicate it... The first thing that comes to my mind is that you're updating a record with no Id, but that'd be a dmlException with a different message. Is any of your code using a particularly archaic API version (I think v18.0 and v24.0 are the two big "things really changed after this point" marks)?

Comment: Bingo! The main class is apparently on API version 16.0.  Which... ugh.

Comment: Closer hit: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000Br6nKSAR . Sounds like a flavor of NPE.